# How to delete MetaMask accounts - if I recover an account from the seed phrase, can I access also the old related accounts?

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

**Premiss**

I'm really new to this, I would like to share my art throught KnownOrigin and other ETH based art websites in order to make them unique. Now that I started to understand the blockchain and basic wallets, I found MetaMask as an option to log-in into [KnownOrigin](https://knownorigin.io/).
I was firstly using FortMatic but it seemed a bit odd so I dropped it. MetaMask really seem to be cutting edge with web3 stuff.

**Questions**

I linked [KnownOrigin](https://knownorigin.io/) with MetaMask but with the wrong address, so I created a new account solely for that purpose.

*Now I have an unused account.*

Online, the only solution to "delete" an account from MetaMask seems to be to simply disconnect/reinstall the plug-in and recover the account from the seed phrase. Problem is, what happens to other accounts created inside MetaMask? (to be clear, I don't have external accounts linked)

It seems like this will recover only the first account, what happens to the others?
What should I do? Is there another way to delete accounts from MetaMask?

**Conclusion**

In general, I find this "account system" a bit confusing, I don't really know what is recoverable, where the wallets are and how they work fully.

Software wallets seems easier to understand, I would really like to continue using MetaMask because it really seems like the future, and also seems to be the best way at the moment (imho).

**Setup**

I have Firefox and the MetaMask app installed in my iPhone. Have access to Linux, Mac and Windows in case this is necessary.

Comment: yeah, folks at MetaMaks have insulted our intelligence by not providing the Delete option. Because if they think we are so dumb to delete our accounts then they owe us an apology and must provide `Delete` function in the next release

Comment: I think it is not that dumb to hide the delete option, but the complete lack of it is a bit odd. If you don't want to give the option to avoid responsibility or whatnot you can simply add a "hide" option, so I can hide more important wallets or unwanted ones... It can be so simple...
At least they have a "rename" option, so with unwanted wallets you can rename them when you will find an use for them.

Answer (score 1):

Each account has a different private key. you can import your other accounts with the private keys. note that there is no way to recover the account without the private key. If you lose it so you lose the wallet. don't share your private keys with anyone.

How to export your private keys:
Press the three dots on the top right side, press account details, press the export private key button.

again. don't share your private keys with anyone. the private key is basically the account itself.

Comment: Yup, but inside 1 MetaMask itself you can have multiple "accounts". I'm referring to those single accounts not to the general MetaMask account.
Maybe I got this all wrong and actually MetaMask is just a container for multiple wallets/accounts. Is this correct? 
So if I got this right, I have to store keys for EVERY SINGLE wallet created inside MetaMask... The confusing part is that I only have 1 12-word phrase. It didn't prompted me with new passphrases for each wallet. Why?

Comment: I dont know the answer to your second question but I know that each account in the wallet has a different private key. this is so that you can import multiple wallets and manage them from the same place.

Comment: That is really helpful already, thanks!